# What is the coordinate definition of holomorphic vector fields?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

We can write a holomorphic vector field in local co-ordinates as $X=X^i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z_i}$, where $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z_i}$ forms a local frame for $T^{(1,0)}M$. My questions are

1. Does $X^i$ have to be holomorphic functions?
2. Can we say that $\dfrac{\partial X^i}{\partial \bar{z}^j}=0$ for all $i,j$?
3. If 2 is not true, then what is the right co-ordinate condition on $X^i$s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. is right due to the definition of the holomorphic vector field.
2. is also right.

Comment: What exactly is the standard definition of holomorphic vector fields?

Comment: You can see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198410/what-is-a-holomorphic-vector-field?rq=1

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Comment: Sure thing. Just please remember to accept the answer when you are satisfied that you accept it. :)

Comment: No problem. This is good for me.